# golang producer consumer number of messages received

Tags: go, channel, consumer, producer

I have written producer-consumer pattern in golang. Reading multiple csv files and processing records. I am reading all records of csv file in one go.

I want to log percentage of processing completion in interval of 5% of total records including all csv files. for e.g I have 3 csv to process & each have 20,30,50 rows/records (so in total 100 records to process) want to log progress when 5 records are processed.

```
func processData(inputCSVFiles []string) {
    producerCount := len(inputCSVFiles)
    consumerCount := producerCount

    link := make(chan []string, 100)
    wp := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wc := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    wp.Add(producerCount)
    wc.Add(consumerCount)

    for i := 0; i < producerCount; i++ {
        go produce(link, inputCSVFiles[i], wp)
    }

    for i := 0; i < consumerCount; i++ {
        go consume(link, wc)
    }
    wp.Wait()
    close(link)
    wc.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Completed data migration process for all CSV data files.")
}

func produce(link chan<- []string, filePath string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    records := readCsvFile(filePath)
    totalNumberOfRecords := len(records)
    for _, record := range records {
        link <- record
    }
}

func consume(link <-chan []string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for record := range link {
        // process csv record
    }
}
```

Comment: `I want to log percentage of processing completion in interval of 5% of total records including all csv files.` You need to know the total set of records to compute that. Or to accept that until the value is built the results will be weird.

Comment: just trying some stuff. But it would have been a better question if the code was reproducible. https://go.dev/play/p/YcoZl16UuR3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used atomic variable & counter channel where consumer will push count when record is processed & other goroutine will read from channel & calculate total processed record percentage.

```
var progressPercentageStep float64 = 5.0
var totalRecordsToProcess int32

func processData(inputCSVFiles []string) {
        producerCount := len(inputCSVFiles)
        consumerCount := producerCount
        link := make(chan []string, 100)
        counter := make(chan int, 100)
        defer close(counter)
        wp := &sync.WaitGroup{}
        wc := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    
        wp.Add(producerCount)
        wc.Add(consumerCount)
    
        for i := 0; i < producerCount; i++ {
            go produce(link, inputCSVFiles[i], wp)
        }

        go progressStats(counter)

        for i := 0; i < consumerCount; i++ {
            go consume(link, wc)
        }
        wp.Wait()
        close(link)
        wc.Wait()
        
    }
    
    func produce(link chan<- []string, filePath string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        records := readCsvFile(filePath)
        atomic.AddInt32(&totalRecordsToProcess, int32(len(records)))
        for _, record := range records {
            link <- record
        }
    }
    
    func consume(link <-chan []string,counter chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()
        for record := range link {
            // process csv record
            counter <- 1
        }
    }
    
func progressStats(counter <-chan int) {
    var feedbackThreshold = progressPercentageStep
    for count := range counter {
        totalRemaining := atomic.AddInt32(&totalRecordsToProcess, -count)
        donePercent := 100.0 * processed / totalRemaining
        // log progress
        if donePercent >= feedbackThreshold {
            log.Printf("Progress ************** Total Records: %d, Processed Records : %d, Processed Percentage: %.2f **************\n", totalRecordsToProcess, processed, donePercent)
            feedbackThreshold += progressPercentageStep
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is racy to read totalRecordsToProcess without atomic.

Comment: beware `link` is `chan<- []string`, but you are sending `record`, a string.

Comment: I fixed the race for you. For the rest your compiler will help you to fix the other issues.